# Laptop stuck at boot menu screen

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader, start-menu, boot-manager

My lenovo laptop is stuck at boot menu. On starting the laptop the boot menu loads up and shows various boot options but on selecting a particular option , the boot menu load again . [image]

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that the boot process is unable to find a bootable partition.  If you plug in a bootable USB disk (eg Linux rescue disk), does it boot off that?

If you are certain there is a useable OS on the hard drive, you may want to go into BIOS and toggle between UEFI and MBR booting.

Comment: It does not boot from bootable pendrive

Comment: can you try to boot  via a dvd ? You could try to repair with disk if its windows once this works